# Is it possible to find related SubscriptionID from ExecutionID data in ExecutionLogStorage table?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportserver

I am trying to create a process which logs historic subscription errors into a new table.

I've tried to do this by using the data within ExecutionLogStorage, I can't however see how this data relates to a specific SubscriptionID. I can join it to ReportID but as I have multiple subscriptions per report this doesn't achieve what I need.

I have tried googling various scripts, none actually link directly to SubscriptionID.

I need to be able to record a log of successful and unsuccessful executions of subscriptions throughout the day, which will then be inserted into a new table via a SQL Server Agent Job.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query :

```
SELECT
sj.[name] AS [Job Name],
rs.SubscriptionID,
c.[Name] AS [Report Name],
c.[Path],
su.Description,
su.EventType,
su.LastStatus,
su.LastRunTime


FROM msdb..sysjobs AS sj 

INNER JOIN ReportServer..ReportSchedule AS rs
ON sj.[name] = CAST(rs.ScheduleID AS NVARCHAR(128)) 

INNER JOIN ReportServer..Subscriptions AS su
ON rs.SubscriptionID = su.SubscriptionID

INNER JOIN ReportServer..[Catalog] c
ON su.Report_OID = c.ItemID
```

This should give you a list of all reports with subscriptions and it's history.

You should be able to base this as a guide to do what ever else you need to do.